# What AWS service to use for running batch jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to run java code that talk to MySql db in AWS and does some ETL on a nightly frequency. Which AWS service can I used for this?

Comment: Is this existing code? Where is it running (eg on an Amazon EC2 instance)? How long does it take to run (asking because AWS Lambda functions can run for a maximum of 15 minutes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the following:

- [AWS Glue ETL](https://aws.amazon.com/glue)
- [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/)
- AWS [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) / [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) [scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html)